# Como evitar pegar más contenido en un div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Quiera saber como evitar que se añada más contenido en el div. El máximo de caracteres es 30, pero si pegas contenido habiendo escrito 29 caracteres, se llegara a pegar dicho contenido y ya no respetara el limite que es de 30. Además, otro problema que veo es que al momento de hacer un  **ctrl + a** habiendo escrito los 30 caracteres, NO permite seleccionar todo el contenido, solo habiendo escrito 29 caracteres AHÍ recién funciona.

```js
function limitar(e, contenido, caracteres) {
            var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;

            if (unicode == 8 || unicode == 46 || unicode == 13 || unicode == 9 || unicode == 37 || unicode == 39 || unicode == 38 || unicode == 40)
                return true;

            if (contenido.length >= caracteres) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

```css
.container{
 background: orange;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div contentEditable=true onkeydown="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)">Contenido</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No se puede usar un Input en lugar de un div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre

> ctrl + a habiendo escrito los 30 caracteres,

Es un problema con el evento, se ejecuta antes que tu div tome el caracter, deberias cambiar el `onkeydown`, por un `onkeypress`

Luego, con el problema del paste, como ya mencionaron deberia arreglase con un `onpaste` pero si queres otra opcion tenes el evento DOMSubtreeModified, con el cual verias los cambios hechos en tu div.

En tu javascript, debes generar un evento que se atienda al cambio en tu div metiendole un id.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="editableDiv" contentEditable=true >Contenido</div>
</div>
```

Luego el evento propiamente dicho, este ejemplo lo limita a 4.

```
$("body").on('DOMSubtreeModified', "#editableDiv", function() {
   if ($("#editableDiv").html().length >= 4) {
               $("#editableDiv").html($("#editableDiv").html().substring(0, 4));
               $("#editableDiv").focus();
            }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad `onpaste` y retornar un `false`, anexo ejemplo:

```html
<div contentEditable=true onpaste="return false;" >Contenido</div>
```

En tu caso quedaría algo así:

```js
function limitar(e, contenido, caracteres) {
            
            if (contenido.length >= caracteres) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

```css
.container{
 background: orange;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
 <div contentEditable=true onkeypress="return limitar(event, this.textContent, 30)" onpaste="return false;">Contenido</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Se tiene que cambiar el `onkeydown` por el `onkeypress` ya que es lo que evita que sigas modificando tu texto al llegar a 30 caracteres.

Espero te ayude. Saludos.